# solving recurences

Tags: math, recurrence

T(n)=T(n-1) + lgn
My approach is:

Substituting n-1,n-2,n-3
Finally we get,
T(n)=T(1) + lg 2 +lg 3 and so lg n
=> T(n) = lg(2*3*4*5 n)
Hence T(n)=lg(n!).

But they give the answer as nlgn.

Comment: Try posting this on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Hint: Stirling's approximation.

Comment: Are you sure they're asking for a closed-form solution for T(n)? That is, do they say the answer is `T(n) = n lg(n)`?

Answer (score 2):

Is this a problem for computing complexity? If so then both you and "they" are correct.

```
O(lg(n!)) = O(lg(n^n)) = O(n lg(n))
```

More rigorously, from [Stirling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) formula:

```
lg(n!) = n lg(n) - n + O(ln(n))
```

Therefore

```
O(lg(n!)) = O(n lg(n)) + O(n) + O(ln(n)) = O(n lg(n))
```